# parsing Table in json obj

Tags: c#, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7n29.png)

I got the API response as shown in picture in json format. But I need to parse it in such a way that I only want to consider Rows and Columns from Table - 0 and exclude rest of them.  I tried multiple options, one of this as given below but it did not work. New bee to c#. Pls advise

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceInfo))
        {
            JObject metrics_json = JObject.Parse(resourceInfo);

            res = metrics_json["tables"].First.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Json string that u receive is the following

```
var resourceInfo = "[{ 'TableName': 'Table_0', 'Columns':['Column_1'], 'Rows':['Row_1']}]";
```

You can create a class to store the deserialized object

```
public class Table
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string[] Columns { get; set; }
    public string[] Rows { get; set; }
}
```

and you should be able to deserialize the Json and get the value by using

```
var tables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table>>(resourceInfo);
Console.WriteLine(tables[0].TableName);
Console.WriteLine(tables[0].Columns[0]);
Console.WriteLine(tables[0].Rows[0]);
```

the result will be

```
Table_0
Column_1
Row_1
```

Comment: It did not work since Tables itself is an array. Column has two values separated by comma as shown in pic. Column has 7 indexes and each row has those 7 values corresponding to columns.

How this can be parsed ? I tried variety of options, no luck.

Comment: can you provide the json string?